# flask-restful - resource class for current request

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

**THE QUESTION**

All of my app's routes are defined via flask-restful Resources.
How can I find the resource object/class that is processing current request?

**WHY I WANT THIS**

I wanted to log all exceptions raised while processing requests. I connect to `flask.got_request_exception`, as described in http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#signals and something like this works well:

```
from flask import got_request_exception, request

def log_exception(sender, exception, **extra):
    logger.info("URL: {}, Exception: {}".format(request.url, type(exception).__name__))

got_request_exception.connect(log_exception, app)
```

The only problem is that I want to log some of the request data, but not all the data - e.g. I'd like to hide passwords. I think it would be a good idea to have logging-data-logic together with request processing logic, like this:

```
from flask import request
import flask_restful

class SomeResource(flask_restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        # ... GET processing
    def log_data(self):
        # log all body params
        return request.get_json()

class Login(flask_restful.Resource):
   def post(self):
       # ... authentication
   def log_data(self):
       # log selected body params
       return {'login': request.get_json()['login'], 'password': 'HIDDEN!'}
```

and than use it in my `log_exception`:

```
from flask import got_request_exception, request

def log_exception(sender, exception, **extra):
    resource_class = # THIS IS THE THING I'M MISSING
    logger.info("URL: {}, Exception: {}, Data: {}".format(request.url, type(exception).__name__), 
                resource_class.log_data())

got_request_exception.connect(log_exception, app)
```

But maybe this should be done other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of inheriting from `flask_restful.Resource` your want to inherit all from a custom resource

```py
class MyResource(flask_restful.Resource):
    def dispatch_request(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(MyResource,self).dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as ex:
            setattr(ex, "_raised_by", self)
            raise ex
```

and then you can use the exception handler

```py
def log_exception(sender, exception, **extra):
    _raised_by = getattr(exception, "_raised_by", None)
    if _raised_by:
        print(_raised_by)
    property("URL: {}, Exception: {}".format(request.url, type(exception).__name__))
```

Here is complete code I tried

```py
from flask import request, Flask
import flask_restful

app = Flask(__name__)

api = flask_restful.Api(app)


class MyResource(flask_restful.Resource):
    def dispatch_request(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(MyResource,self).dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as ex:
            setattr(ex, "_raised_by", self)
            raise ex

# MyResource = flask_restful.Resource

class SomeResource(MyResource):
    def get(self):
        raise Exception("Not implemented")

    def log_data(self):
        # log all body params
        return request.get_json()


class Login(MyResource):
    def post(self):
        raise Exception("Not implemented")

    def log_data(self):
        # log selected body params
        return {'login': request.get_json()['login'], 'password': 'HIDDEN!'}


from flask import got_request_exception, request

api.add_resource(Login, '/login')
api.add_resource(SomeResource, '/some')


def log_exception(sender, exception, **extra):
    _raised_by = getattr(exception, "_raised_by", None)
    if _raised_by:
        print(_raised_by)
    property("URL: {}, Exception: {}".format(request.url, type(exception).__name__))


got_request_exception.connect(log_exception, app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Edit-1: 5th Aug**

As commented by @jbet, in case one wants to get the processing class always a cleaner option would be to use the `MyResource` as below

```py
from flask import g

class MyResource(flask_restful.Resource):
    def dispatch_request(self, *args, **kwargs):
        g.processed_by = self
        return super(MyResource,self).dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for.

Comment: I modified a little your `dispatch_request` and instead of `try/except` and `setattr` i just do `from flask import g`, `g.processed_by = self` before calling `super().dispatch_request`.

I think this is cleaner solution and also works when request ended up without exception.

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a nice way to get access to your object once the logging method had been called by signals.

If you were willing to handle all possible cases, you could create your own custom exceptions that call the log_data method on your class.

Instead, I opted to handle logging myself in a base class. Simple example for you, I just used print functions, but you could call app.logging.info instead.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import flask_restful

app = Flask(__name__)
api = flask_restful.Api(app)

class MyCustomResource(flask_restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        try:
            self.my_get()
        except Exception as exception:
            # Will catch all errors in your subclass my_get method
            print("exception caught")
            print(request.url)
            print(type(exception).__name__)
            print(self.log_data())

            # Re-raise if you want (or not)
            raise exception

    def my_get(self):
        # Python equivalent of virtual method
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def log_data(self):
        # Python equivalent of virtual method
        raise NotImplementedError()


class SomeResource(MyCustomResource):
    def my_get(self):
        # Example unknown error occurs here
        raise Exception("error!")
        return "some data"

    def log_data(self):
        # Called by parent
        return "some logging data for the object"

api.add_resource(SomeResource, "/")
```

If you wanted to dig deeper into the flask restful source you could also monkey patch (or build your own package) whatever method is calling get/post.